# will_paginate & filterrific: undefined method `total_pages' for #<Array:0x007f9f6b4a3320>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, filterrific

I'm trying to use [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) in conjunction with [filterrific](https://github.com/jhund/filterrific). But I'm getting the following error:

> undefined method `total_pages' for # Array:0x007f9f6b4a3320>

My controller action:

```
  def index
    @filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
      current_user.assessments,
      params[:filterrific],
      :select_options => {
        sorted_by: Assessment.options_for_sorted_by      },
        :persistence_id => false,
    ) or return
    @assessments = @filterrific.find.page(params[:page]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10).sort_by &:created_at
    @assessments.reverse!
  end
```

View:

```
<%= render(
  partial: 'list',
  locals: { assessments: @assessments }
) %>

</div>
```

Partial:

```
<div id="filterrific_results">



    <% @assessments.each do |assessment| %>
    ....
    <% end %>

</div>


<%= will_paginate assessments %>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try adding a new  file to config/initilizers and add this line `require 'will_paginate/array'`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are casting an ActiveRecord collection proxy to an array with the following two methods:

- `.sort_by`
- `.reverse`

Make sure to set the order using an ActiveRecord method. This should work: `.order('created_at DESC')`.

You are also calling the pagination method twice: `.page` and `.paginate`. Once should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid calling sort_by over paginated collection. Add scope to Assessments and specify the scope for filterrific.

```
asessment.rb
class Assessment < ActiveRecord::Base
    filterrific(
      available_filters: [
        :oldest_first
      ]
    )
    scope :oldest_first, lambda { order('created_at ASC') }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're calling both ".page" and ".paginate". I'm ok with below code. I know you already solved this because the question is posted last two years but I'm just sharing my experience for friend who will face with this issue in later.

```
    @filterrific.find.page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
```